# 'Unexpected token d' when trying to add objects to a Javascript Object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an empty object within `hotKeyService` as below:

```
{hotKeys: [
    ]
}
```

I want to add a load of objects into this array, to give an end result of the form:

```
{hotKeys: [
       "demoBtn1":{
                   keyCode: 49,
                   keyShortcut: "1",
                   label: "button"
                  },
       "demoBtn2":{
                   keyCode: 50,
                   keyShortcut: "2",
                   label: "button"
                  },
    ]
}
```

Currently my code is:

```
hotKeyService.hotKeys.push(attrs.id);
var arrayRow = hotKeyService.hotKeys.length - 1;
var currentObj = JSON.parse(hotKeyService.hotKeys[arrayRow]);
currentObj.keyCode = attrs.keyCode;
currentObj.keyShortcut = attrs.keyShortcut;
currentObj.label = attrs.label;
```

At the point where I try and parse JSON for `currentObj`, I receive the error. If I do not parse I get a `Cannot assign to read only property 'keyCode' of demoBtn1` error, which I read is because the object needs parsing.

How do I populate the object as I am expecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't have "keys" (they have props tho, but that's out of the question). I believe you wanted to use `{}` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays consist of a list of values:

```
[ foo, bar, baz ]
```

Not a series of key: value pairs (that's for objects):

```
{ a: foo, b: bar, c: baz }
```

The values in an array can, of course, be objects:

```
[ { foo: {} }, { bar: {} }, { baz: {} } ]
```